# Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$id in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a confusion and I need a help to solve.

I am trying to add a record to a table that depends on the initial record, it is an event log table related to the initial registration of a call record.

As I try to do this it is with an input hidden, but it does not receive the id and it generates the following error (Undefined property:Illuminate\Support\Collection::$id).

This is part of the view with the record button of the incidences.

```
@foreach ($data as $call)
<tr class="active">
    <td align="center">{{ ++$i }}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{{ $call->created_at->format('d - m - Y') }}</td>
    <td>{{ $call->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $call->last_name }}</td>
    <td align="center">
        @if($call->type == 1)         
            <span class="label label-info">Saliente</span>        
        @else         
            <span class="label label-success">Entrante</span>        
        @endif
    </td>
    <td>{{ $call->phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ $call->movil }}</td>
    <td align="center">

        <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="{{ route('calls.show',$call->id) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Detalle de llamada"> <i class="material-icons">info_outline</i> </a>

        @permission('role-edit')
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{ route('calls.edit',$call->id) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar registro de llamada"> <i class="material-icons">create</i> </a>
        @endpermission

        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="{{ route('comments.create', $call->id) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Registrar incidencia"> <i class="material-icons">event</i> </a>

        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['calls.destroy', $call->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}

            @permission('role-delete')
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar llamada"><i class="material-icons delete-white">delete</i></button>
            @endpermission

        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

This is part of the view where the issue is logged, but I need to pass the id in the hidden field.

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'comments.store','method' => 'POST')) !!}

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                {!! Form::select('call_id', $calls, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Seleccionar cliente']) !!} <!--This is the select-->

                {{ Form::hidden('call_id', $calls->id) }} <!--This is the hidden mode-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
                {!! Form::text('name', null, array('placeholder' => 'Registrar incidencia','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
            </div> 
            <span class="input-group-btn">                  
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Guardar">
                    <i class="material-icons">save</i>
                </button> 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The error generated by the view is:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$id
```

These are my methods for the controller (CommentController).

```
public function create()
    {
        $calls = Call::orderBy('id', 'asc')->lists('name', 'id');

        return view('comments.create', compact('calls'));
    }


public function store(Request $request)
{
    //return $request->all();

    $this->validate($request, [
      'name'        => 'required|unique:categories|max:255',
    ]);

    $comments = Comment::create([
        'name'          => $request->get('name'),
        'call_id'       => $request->get('call_id'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('comments.index')
                    ->with('success','Comentario agregado correctamente!!!');
}
```

This is my route method.

```
Route::resource('comments','CommentController');
```

This is the call log view, when clicking the orange button calls the comment view to record an issue.

[image]

This is the view of record of incidents, here I have the dropdown but ideally instead of a dropdown can receive the ID of the record you select from the previous view.

[image]

Someone who can guide me, since I have used several methods and I have not been able to solve it.

Comment: The lists() method returns an array. You are trying to call the property ID, hence the error. You need to reference it as $calls['id']

Comment: Thank you very much Rob Fonseca, apply your recommendations, but now the error is as follows: Undefined index: $id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\crminmobiliario\resources\views\comments\includes\new.blade.php).

Comment: Can you dd() the $calls array in your controller and add it to your posting?

Comment: @RobFonseca This is the array that returns:Collection {#287 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    1 => "Alma Josefina"
    2 => "Julio Cesar"
    3 => "Julio Cesar"
  ]
}

Comment: That was making a dd of calls in CommentController.

Comment: You have 3 items in the array but are only trying to get 1 call ID? Lists() doesn't give you the nodes 'id' and 'name', it creates a multi dimensional array keyed as 'id' => 'name'. If you want to get the ID of the first array item, you would have to reference it as key($calls[0]). That should output 1 for the key of the first array item Alma Josefina

Comment: Sorry @RobFonseca last night was a bit late but if I want to pass the ID dynamically, how would the correct form be?

Comment: So you want to fill in the ID when someone picks a choice from the select drop down? You would want to use a onchange event on that drop down and have jQuery fill it in.

Comment: With a dropdown brings me the records, I can select them and create the record, but I really want to take the id and pass it hidden to the comments view and this allows me to create the record.

Comment: Correct, so when you change the drop down (let's say you choose 'Julio Caesar'), you want it to populate the hidden input with the ID of 2 or 3?

Comment: No, what it subscribes is that I have a view where I register calls, but to those calls I want to register incidences, when selecting a call record, the ideal would be to dynamically pass the ID to the incident view, that is why I try to pass it hidden and with The assigned ID.

I'm going to place a picture of the call log view and the call log to record the issue.

Comment: Hey @RobFonseca greetings, I built the different module until I figured it out another way, as I was trying to make it lack a bit of logic.

Create two modules, one handles the incoming and outgoing calls and to these calls I can assign incidents or comments, I used the select input taking the ID of each record, so I can know which call record belongs to registering an incident, thanks for your help, it helped me a lot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the confusion and method as follows:

The button to create the incidence in the view I defined it as follows:

```
@foreach ($data as $call)

<a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="{{ route('comments.create', ['id' => $call->id]) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Registrar incidencia"> <i class="material-icons">event</i> </a>

@endforeach
```

In the create method of CommentController I structured it as follows:

```
public function create($id)
{
    $calls = DB::table('calls')->find($id);

    return view('comments.create', compact('calls'));
}
```

The store method of CommentController I structured it as follows:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //return $request->all();

    $rules = [
        'call_id'                   => 'required',
        'comments_name'             => 'required',
    ];

    $messages = [
        'call_id.required'           => 'Debe seleccionar un código de llamada',
        'comments_name.required'    => 'Debe ingresar incidencia',
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);       

    $comments = Comment::create([
        'comments_name'     => $request->get('comments_name'),
        'call_id'           => $request->get('call_id'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('calls.index')
                    ->with('success','Incidencia agregada correctamente!!!');
}
```

The labels in the view create incidents are as follows:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'comments.store','method' => 'POST')) !!}

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            {!! Form::text('comments_name', null, array('placeholder' => 'Nombres','class' => 'form-control')) !!} 
            {{ Form::hidden('call_id', $calls->id) }}
            </div> 
            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="{{ route('calls.index') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Retornar">
                    <i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
                </a>   

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Guardar">
                    <i class="material-icons">save</i>
                </button> 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And I defined the following route in the routes file:

```
Route::get('comments/create/{id}', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'as' => 'comments.create',
    'uses' => 'CommentController@create'
]);
```

This way you can create a call log with a list of many incidents.

If this method should be improved please give me the recommendations, but it was the way in which I could do it.

Thanks @RobFonseca and @CarlosAdames for your comments and help.

Answer (score 1):

The lists method returns a collection instance. You need to convert the Collection into a plain array using the all method.

In your controller try this:

$calls = Call::orderBy('id', 'asc')->lists('name', 'id')->all();

You can read more about it in the following link [The lists Method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0)

Let me know if your problem is solved.

Comment: Hi @CarlosAdames , I was reviewing and applying these parameters:

In the store method in CommentsController

$ Calls = Call :: orderBy ('id', 'asc') -> lists ('name', 'id');

In the view just add these fields:

{!! Form :: open (array ('route' => 'comments.store', 'method' => 'POST')) !!}

{!! Form :: text ('comments_name', null, array ('placeholder' => 'Names', 'class' => 'form-control'))

<Input name = "call_id" type = "hidden" value = "$ call-> id">

{!! Form :: close () !!}

Comment: But when I save the changes I get this error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`erpinmobiliaria`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_call_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`call_id`) REFERENCES `calls` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `comments` (`comments_name`, `call_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Prueba de incidencia con campo oculto 1., $call->id, 2017-02-04 01:18:50, 2017-02-04 01:18:50))